Whether or not the root number of GL$_3\times$GL$_2$ $L$-function $L(s, F \otimes g)$ contains the coefficients $\lambda_g(n)$ of $g$?
$\DeclareMathOperator\GL{GL}\DeclareMathOperator\SL{SL}$Let $p$ and $q$ be two distinct primes. Let $$\Gamma_0(p)= \left\{   g\in \GL_3(\mathbb{Z}):g \equiv \left(\begin{matrix} \ast &\ast&\ast \\
\ast &\ast&\ast   \\0&0&\ast \end{matrix}\right)    \mod p  \right\}$$
Let $F$ be a normalized Hecke-Maass form of type $\nu=(\nu_1,\nu_2)$ for the congruent subgroup $\Gamma_0(p)$ of $\SL(3, \mathbb{Z})$ with trivial nebentypus. Let $g\in S^\ast_k(q)$
be a newform of level $q$ on $\SL(2, \mathbb{Z})$ with trivial nebentypus.
Let $L(s,F \otimes g)$ be the Rankin-Selberg convolution $L$-function which is given by $L(s,F \otimes g)=\sum_{n.m\ge 1}\lambda_F(n,m)\lambda_g(n)(nm^2)^{-s}$. Let $$\Lambda(s,F\otimes g)=Q(F\otimes g)^{s/2} L_\infty(s, F \otimes g)L(s, F \otimes g)$$ be the completed $L$-function, where $Q(F\otimes g)$ is the conductor of $L(s, F\otimes g)$. Then we have the functional equation
\begin{equation}
\Lambda(s, F\otimes g)=\epsilon(s, F \otimes g) \overline{\Lambda(F\otimes g,1-\bar{s})}.
\end{equation}
My question is: whether or not the root number $\epsilon(s, F \otimes g)$ contains the coefficients $\lambda_g(n)$ of $g$? How we compute the local factors  $\epsilon_v(s, F \otimes g)$ at places $v\le \infty$, especially at the places $v=\infty$ and $v=p,q$?
Note that in this paper (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1207.3421v3), the $\GL_2\times \GL_2$ Rankin-Selberg $L$-functions for different levels has been given in Section 2.3. A good detailed analysis has also been given at MO in this post Root number of the Rankin-Selberg convolution of two newforms. However, for $\GL_3\times \GL_2 $, there seem no a clear description, as far as I am concerned. So if any expert leans some information on this question, please show a guide or certain references.
Many thanks in advance.

The only self-dual $\mathrm{GL}_3$ Hecke-Maass forms on $\Gamma_0(p)$ are oldforms from $\mathrm{SL}_3(\mathbb{Z})$. Did you mean $\Gamma_0(p^2)$? Those are the ones arising as the adjoint lift of $\mathrm{GL}_2$ Hecke-Maass forms of level $p$.

In any case, you might gain some intuition for thinking about what would happen if you replaced $F$ with the $\mathrm{GL}_3$ minimal parabolic Eisenstein series of level $1$ and trivial spectral parameters, so that $\Lambda(s,F \otimes g) = \Lambda(s,g)^3$ and $\epsilon(s,F \otimes g) = \epsilon(s,g)^3$. So of course the epsilon factor will not be independent of $g$.

Sorry, my fault. The forms I consider are  just the $GL_3$ Hecke-Maass forms of level $p$. remedied.

@PeterHumphries Yes. However, in that situation, it seems that $\varepsilon(s,g)=\pm 1$? It appears that $\varepsilon(s,g)$ equals some complex number times $\lambda_g(q)\sqrt{q}$, which finally is independent of $g$.

? $\lambda_g(q) \sqrt{q}$ is not independent of $g$.

Why would you even suspect this?  I don't understand the motivation for your question.

Maybe I didn't put my concern more clearly.  The question may be to ask "if the $\varepsilon$-factor contains coefficients $\lambda_g(n)$ ". Since one may note that $\lambda_g(q)\sqrt{q}=\pm1$ which do not contain the coefficients of $g$.  I speculate $\varepsilon(s,F\otimes g)$ probably depends of the weight or the level of $g$, but has no the coefficient  $\lambda_g(n)$ of $g$ involved.

What does it mean for an $\varepsilon$-factor, or any function of $g$, to contain other functions of $g$?  Does it mean that you ask for an explicit expression of the former in terms of the latter?  Is it just the opposite of "is independent of" (your original title)?  What would it mean, rigorously, for the answer to be "no"?

@PeterHumphries, Kimball, LSpice  Sorry to spend your time, the point of the departure looks blur for every expert here. Perhaps the quick way is to solve all puzzles is to determine the exact form of $\varepsilon$-factor directly.  Enlightened  by Section 2.3 in the above referred Holowinsky-Templier's paper on $GL_2\times GL_2$ case, the biggest problem lie on what is the $\varepsilon_\infty(s, F\otimes g)$, while other places at $v=p,q$ might follow in a similar way.

Note that if $F=\text{sym}^2f$ a special $GL_3$-form, Holowinsky, Munshi and Qi have claimed $\varepsilon_\infty(s, F\otimes g)=\pm 1$. Then what to be  said if $F$ is a general  $GL_3$ Hecke-Maass forms of prime level $p$, say??? This is the heart of my question.
.

You need to be more specific in what you are actually asking. The root number is always of absolute value $1$, but its exact value will depend on the local components of the underlying automorphic representations. Perhaps you should try to read my answer for the $\mathrm{GL}_2 \times \mathrm{GL}_2$ setting and work out the details for yourself (which is the kind of task I would give to my graduate students).

@PeterHumphries Thanks for help. Yes,  I have referred your work in the post; that is really a fabulous detailed analysis! Observe that now the three Langlands parameters of $F$ are up to ${v_1,v_2}\in \mathbb{C}$, not the weight in $GL_2\times GL_2$ case. I even searched your linked paper of A. W. Knapp.  But, I still can not be sure the local factor of $\varepsilon_v(s,F\otimes g)$ at $v=\infty$. I personally think $\varepsilon_v(s,F\otimes g)\in {\pm 1, \pm i}$ only depending on the weight of $g$ as well as ${v_1,v_2}$.

I don't understand the difficulty you're having with this. The epsilon factor is multiplicative w.r.t. isobaric sums. If your $\mathrm{GL}3$ automorphic representation is unramified at the archimedean place (e.g. in the Maass form setting), then its local component is just an unramified principal series representation, so this does not influence its epsilon factor. That is, $\epsilon{\infty}(s,F \otimes g) = \epsilon_{\infty}(s,g)^3$.

Thanks for clarification. That is the answer! Why I can not understand is that, as you referred in the post (https://mathoverflow.net/questions/256987/root-number-of-the-rankin-selberg-convolution-of-two-newforms), for $GL_2\times GL_2$ case, the $ \varepsilon$-factor for $L(s, f\otimes g)$ at $\infty$ is $\varepsilon_\infty(s,f\otimes g)=(-1)^{\max{k_f, k_g}+1}$. This depends on $f$ also.

That's because $f$ is not a Maass form; it's a holomorphic modular form, so its local component at the archimedean place is a discrete series representation, which is ramified.

Great thanks for taking your time, dear Prof. Humphries, to show so many things. All puzzlements are clarified. Great thanks! Your help are really appreciated.
